# Least squares with very large sparse matrix

Tags: octave, linear-algebra, least-squares

What is the best function to obtain a least squares minimum solution from a linear problem like `Ax = b` in Octave, with `A` very large but sparse?

`x = A\b` gives the error:

> SparseQR: sparse matrix QR factorization filled" that I don't understand.

Comment: "A" matrix is a matrix of square matrices, n*3 matrices: for each row, the first is a diagonal one, the second is simply sparse and the third is an eye matrix

Comment: to be really honest, I delete some rows before computation (they are data from real world, so not everything is perfect...), thus the matrix structure is not exactly the one I described

Comment: not an expert in `octave` but I suppose that you do not have enough memory for the QR factorization of `A` (used for the Dulmage-Mendelsohn decomposition, see the octave [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Sparse-Linear-Algebra.html). May be this question is better suited for http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: What version of Octave are you running? Is it installed with libsuitesparse? I do not seem to have an issue with randomly generated sparse matrices, but I do not have your data either.